# JComboBox not painting

Tags: java, swing, combobox, paint

I am having an issue in an interface I am making in Java. It is working correctly for JPanel, JTextField, JCheckBox, JRadioButton and JButton, they all get painted correctly. But JComboBox does not. It only paints whatever background colour has been set.

Due to the projects complexity, none of these components are added to a container, but are virtually present, and are painted onto the container, other components are working, so I don't think that is the issue: Here is the creation code:

```
paintableComponent = new JComboBox(new String[]{"test"});
```

and the paint code, this is inside a pseudo component

```
if(this.getParentComponent() != null && this.getParentComponent() instanceof Component && !((Component)this.getParentComponent()).getValue("style.overflow").equals("visible")){
    g.setClip(this.getParentComponent().getX(), this.getParentComponent().getY(), this.getParentComponent().getWidth(), this.getParentComponent().getHeight());
}
Graphics oldG = g;
g = g.create(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
paintableComponent.paint(g);
g = oldG;
Iterator<Component> i = children.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    i.next().paint(g);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: for better help sooner edit quesstion with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Turns out the issue was because I was manually setting the bounds of the real component when the pseudo component. This works fine on components with no children, but fails otherwise. 

The solution was to override the setBounds method of the JComboBox, to allow the setting of the childrens bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JComboBox` has children components which have to be layed out. Try to call `jComboInstance.setSize()` before painting to let it layout children.